# What does $array['key'][null] do in php?

Tags: php, arrays, null

So,

In my code one of my variables happened to contain null, which gave me some rather hard to track issues, specifically, it returns something strange.

Below is the print_r of the same array, the first being called as `print_r($array['key'][null])` with the `null` key the second `print_r($array['key'])` without the `null` key So what is the first array?

**First**

```
Array
(
    [parent_access] => 1
    [seasons] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [parent_access] => 1
                    [rounds] => Array
                        (
                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [direct_access] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Second (Note, the entire array below can be seen at https://gist.github.com/4679128)**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => competition
            [status] => 0
            [child_access] => 
            [direct_access] => 1
            [parent_access] => 
            [seasons] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [type] => season
                            [status] => 1
                            [child_access] => 1
                            [direct_access] => 
                            [parent_access] => 
                            [rounds] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [11] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 11
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [21] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 21
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [31] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 31
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [5] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 5
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [15] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 15
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [25] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 25
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [35] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 35
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [8] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [8] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 8
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [18] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 18
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [28] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 28
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [38] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 38
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [10] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 10
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [10] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 10
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [20] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 20
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [30] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 30
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [40] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 40
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [type] => season
                            [status] => 1
                            [child_access] => 1
                            [direct_access] => 
                            [parent_access] => 
                            [rounds] => Array
                                (
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 2
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [12] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 12
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [22] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 22
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [32] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 32
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [6] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 6
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [16] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 16
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [26] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 26
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [36] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 36
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [9] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [type] => round
                                            [status] => 1
                                            [child_access] => 1
                                            [direct_access] => 
                                            [parent_access] => 
                                            [games] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [9] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 9
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [19] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 19
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [29] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 29
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                    [39] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 39
                                                            [type] => game
                                                            [status] => 1
                                                            [child_access] => 1
                                                            [direct_access] => 
                                                            [parent_access] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => competition
            [status] => 1
            [child_access] => 
            [direct_access] => 
            [parent_access] => 
            [seasons] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [type] => season
                            [status] => 1
                            [child_access] => 
                            [direct_access] => 
                            [parent_access] => 
                            [rounds] => Array
                                (
```

Comment: Note that due to character limit I have chopped off the bottom of the second array, but hopefully that part is irrelevant!

Comment: not me, but perhaps you haven't checked the manual and done any research (see ideone in my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ideone.com/pXRVKE

So the `null` is casted to an empty string.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".

Comment: But that doesn't make sense in my case as I don't have any `""` keys in the array, so if it was that then I would expect an undefined index error.

Comment: @Hailwood: if it returns the value - then there is. `var_dump(array_keys($array));` Check the [627th line](https://gist.github.com/4679128#file-gistfile1-php-L627) of your gist PS: always use `var_dump`, not `print_r` to debug

Comment: Ah snap, you are correct, Now to work on how on earth that's getting there!